# Efficient approach for cost-effective modification between states

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, calculation

I am working on an algorithm that needs to calculate the most cost effective way to apply modifications to a list of objects (more specifically lightpoints that have a position, label and state that they do or don't exist). The start and end lists are the exact same size. The start list may be something like the following:

```
Lightpoint(x: 1, y: 2, label: "A")
Lightpoint(x: 2, y: 2, label: "B")
Lightpoint(exists: false)
```

The desired state looks something like this:

```
Lightpoint(x: 1, y: 2, label: "B")
Lightpoint(x: 2, y: 4, label: "A")
Lightpoint(x: 1, y: 1, label: "A")
```

Creating or deleting has a specific cost or amount of money it gives back (let's say 200 for creating and -150 for deleting)
Moving a Lightpoint can cost for example 100
Relabeling a lightpoint can cost for example 50

To solve this we've tried the following approach:

We can create a possible list of moves for each endstate that describes how a specific lightpoint can be moved or modified to be the state it needs to become. (This creates n^2 possible moves because any light can be moved or modified to reach the end state of any other light).

We must then create all possible permutations of these moves and filter out all the impossible moves (for example grabbing the same light twice which isn't possible).

The problem is that calculating a Cartesian Product ends us with n^n possible permutations, which of course can be filtered a bit to exclude impossible situations, but it's still so much that at 10 lightpoints the algorithm takes about 10 seconds to complete the calculation.

What would be a possible alternative way we can calculate (or very nearly approximate) the best solution so that it scales to 50-100 lightpoints in a usable timeframe?

As an example:

```
    //Initial state:

    // A at position (1,1)
    // B at position (2,2)
    // C at position (3,3)

    //Wanted state:

    // B at position (1,1)
    // A at position (2,2)
    // C at position (3,1)

    //possible changes:

    //Solution 1:
    // A moved to (2,2) (cost: 100 for move )
    // B moved to (1,1) (cost: 100 for move )
    // C moved to (3,1) (cost: 100 for move )
    //total cost: 100 + 100 + 100 = 300

    //Solution 2:
    // A changed label to B (cost: 50 for change label)
    // B changed label to A (cost: 50 for change label)
    // C moved to (3,1) (cost: 100 for move )
    //total cost: 50 + 50 + 100 = 200

    //Solution 3:
    // C moved to (1,1) and changed label to A (cost: 100 for move + 50 for change label)
    // A moved to (2,2) and changed label to B (cost: 100 for move + 50 for change label)
    // B moved to (3,1) and changed label to C (cost: 100 for move + 50 for change label)
    //total cost: 100 + 50 + 100 + 50 + 100 + 50 = 450


    //... some other ways to get to our wanted state
```

I have attached the code we created for prototyping for further information about our current implementation: [OptimalAlignment.zip](https://nextcloud.brainworkz.dev/s/fMFdwYACnCPeNHL)

Comment: I can't understand this question. What are the rules for modifying the list? Or is this actually a common algorithmic problem?

Comment: Can't this type of problem be solved by dynamic programming ? It sounds like a Levenshtein distance

Comment: @shingo A lightpoint can't be used more than once to reach the end state because of course the entire end state has to be completed. All the movements or modifications have a specific cost attached to them and I want to find out the cheapest way to apply these modifications to each light to make sure that I reach the endstate in the most cost-effective way.

Comment: This is related to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is often used to calculate the distance between two words. It counts the number of mutations you have to make to transform one word into the other. There are a lot of [C# implementations](https://www.google.com/search?q=levenstein+distance+c%23).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes To me it doesn't feel like it really 100% applies here because we're not just modifying a single item, but an N amount of items which all can only be modified once. And there's multiple ways or solutions to get to our desired state, all with different costs. How would you suggest we apply this algorithm within these specifications?

Comment: "Moving" here refers to arbitrarily changing the x and y value from their current one into any other x and y value, correct? And we trying to make two equal lists or two equal sets (i.e. is there also a notion of moving things in the order of the list)?

Comment: Wait what do you mean each item can only be modified once? It seemed like you might move and then relabel an object

Comment: Levenshtein moves, adds, and removes the characters of a word around. The items are the characters, not the words. So, it does not only modify a single item.

Comment: @AlexLi Yes, Moving refers to a change in X, Y values. Apologies for not being clear in that.

We want to make sure we make the modifications between the begin state and end state in such a way that the total cost is the cheapest it can be. Hypothetically if at the start and end a lightpoint is at the same position but has a different Label it would never make sense to move that light and move another one in its place. So we want to avoid using a different light to reach the endstate. I will edit the original post to include an example

Comment: What does once mean? Can you show how the lightpints are modified in the above example?

Comment: I just modified the original post to include an example of the possible ways a solution could be created. Hopefully that makes it more clear!

Comment: There is also a [weighted levenshtein distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=weighted+levenshtein+distance) where you can apply different weights to different operations.

Comment: Levenstein doesn't make sense to me here since we are comparing sets rather than lists. A greedy strategy should be able to work (fix lights in the same position, then fix lights with the same label), though the optimal strategy will change depending on the values of the weights. Do you want a solution with these exact weight values [200, -150, 100, 50] or something more general?

Comment: I just did a simple debugging, 2 suggestions: 1) I found that the result of `CalculatePathCost` can be cached, and you may cache them first (that's n^2 calculations). 2) Don't use negative score, so that you can stop calculating the cost when it exceeds the cheapest cost. BTW the calculation is not end with n^n possible permutations, but n * n!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [Kuhn-Munkres algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (Hungarian algorithm). It's an algorithm that solves assignment problems with O(N^3) which should be way faster than your current Brute force O(N!) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, Levenshtein distance can't be applied to this problem, cause your lightpoints are not ordered.

I would start by calculating a weight matrix W, with Wij being the cost to transform a lightpoint (index i) from your initial state to a lightpoint (index j) from your end state.

Then I would apply a simplex algorithm (solver) with these equations (binary integer programming)

```
SUM(Cij) = 1 for all i, j fixed.
SUM(Cij) = 1 for all j, i fixed
[MIN] SUM(Wij * Cij)
```

Cij is a boolean variable, 1 indicating that you chose to use transformation with weight Wij, 0 that you didn't.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like a path-finding problem.
your current state is your current node on the navmesh, and the end state is the end goal, each mutation is a new node in the navmesh and the cost is the travel distance between the nodes. With this you could use an A* path finding algorithm to find your cheapest route.